# EN as a repeated subject

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, sujet

Here are a couple of sentences which seem to break a number of rules of grammar:

> Mes amis en sont-ils notifiés ?
> Tous les amis en sont les  invités d'honneur ?

No textbook mentions that EN can be used as a subject, but in the above sentences taken from online and printed sources it looks like one. So, I would like to know if the abovementioned sentences are correct and when EN can be used to repeat the subject.

Thank you in advance for providing the answer to the question.

Comment: The sentences are completely correct. _En_ is not subject, but complement of the verb.

Comment: Well, there is a mistake. It should be _notifiés_.

Answer (score 1):

These sentences are completely correct. *En* is not subject, but complement of the verb.

In *Mes amis en sont-ils notifiés?*, *en* answers: ***de quoi** mes amis sont-ils notifiés?*, and stands in for the object of the notification, which should be found from the context.

Similarly for *Tous les amis en sont les invités d'honneur?*, *en* answers: ***de quoi** les amis sont-ils les invités d'honneur?*, and *en* stands in for some event that should be found in the context.

Comment: Hello, Frank! And very many thanks for your comment!!! You've been very helpful.

Comment: I'd rather say the second sentence answers to ***De** quoi les amis sont-ils les invités d'honneur ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Sounds reasonable. Should I change my answer?

Comment: That would be my choice.

Comment: @jlliagre Done. Thanks!